# Non-standard syntax, use & to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, syntax-error

```
class calcBMI {
public:
    string line;
    string line2;
    fstream search;
    short loop = 0;
    string weight[6];
    string height[6];
    int index[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int i;

    void getWeight() {

        search.open("name.txt"); //Opens the text file in which the user details are stored
        if (search.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(search, line)) { //While the program searches for the lines in the text file
                if (line.find("Current Weight(KG): ") != string::npos) { //If the string "Name" isnt the last word on the line
                    weight[loop] = line; //Assings the strings read from the text file to the array called weight
                    cout << index[loop] << ". " << weight[loop] << endl; //Outputs the index array which loops through the numbers in the array and outputs the weight variable which loops through the strings in the array
                    loop++; //Iterates the loop 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void getHeight() {

        if (search.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(search, line2)) { //While the program searches for the lines in the text file
                if (line2.find("Height") != string::npos) { //If the string "Name" isnt the last word on the line
                    height[loop] = line2; //Assings the strings read from the text file to the array called weight
                    cout << index[loop] << ". " << height[loop] << endl; //Outputs the index array which loops through the numbers in the array and outputs the weight variable which loops through the strings in the array
                    loop++; //Iterates the loop 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void calculateBMI() {

        calcBMI a;

        a.getWeight;
        a.getHeight;

    }

};
```

Im using a class with functions to calculate a user's BMI by getting data from a txt file. However, i keep getting the following error:'calcBMI::getHeight': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: `getHeight` and `getWeight` are functions, presumably you are trying to call them, in which case, you are missing `()` at the ends of each.

Comment: Oh my god, i've literally been trying to fix it for so long. Thank you so much brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `()` at the end of `getWheight;` and `getHeight;`

```
void calculateBMI()
{
    calcBMI a;

    a.getWeight();
    a.getHeight();
}
```